# How to get server information in CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom

How to get SharePoint server information in CSOM function call? For instance, version of SharePoint server, to which we connected, build number, maybe other technical information. Silly enough, I cannot find relevant function or answer. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't find the csom call for this maybe you could make a simple http request to siteurl/_vti_pvt/service.cnf and parse the result? It contains the server version and encoding.

Comment: @Damjan Tomic, Thank you for this valuable info link, on which I was not aware. I was actually looking for CSOM call because all my other calls are in CSOM. But if nobody will suggest CSOM function, I will use your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retreive that information from the [**Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext_members.aspx) class such as the following.

### Basic Information

```
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl);

#SharePoint Online authentication
$context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, (ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force));

#SharePoint On-Premise authentication
#$context.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials;

$context.ExecuteQuery();

$context.ServerVersion;    
$context.ServerSchemaVersion;
$context.ServerLibraryVersion;
$context.RequestSchemaVersion;
```

### Tenant Information

If you are using SharePoint Online or On-premise multi-tenancy mode *(with Admin Tenant Stub installed guide [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659286.aspx))* by using the assembly **Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll** and the class [**Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration.Tenant**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.online.sharepoint.tenantadministration.tenant_members.aspx)

```
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl);

#SharePoint Online authentication
$context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, (ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force));

#SharePoint On-Premise authentication
#$context.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials;

$tenant = New-object Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration.Tenant($context);

$context.ExecuteQuery();

$tenant.CompatibilityRange;
$tenant.DisplayStartASiteOption;
$tenant.ExternalServicesEnabled;
$tenant.NoAccessRedirectUrl;
$tenant.ResourceQuota;
$tenant.ResourceQuotaAllocated;
$tenant.RootSiteUrl;
$tenant.SharingCapability;
$tenant.StartASiteFormUrl;
$tenant.StorageQuota;
$tenant.StorageQuotaAllocated;
```

Hope it would help you.

Comment: thank you. It worked. It is exactly the info I was looking for. I ve marked your answer as the solution.